# MySQL doesn't return index int

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return an `index(int(11)` and I am not getting anything back from the query.  I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `issuetrack` WHERE 'index'='31'
```

and I see the index in the database.  What would make it not return at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typing error in your query:

```
'index'='31'
```

You're using single quotes instead of backticks. It should be:

```
`index` = '31'
```

Comment: Thanks guys great answer!  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

I think the error is caused by the fact that you should write in the query

```
`index`='31'
```

instead of

```
'index'='31'
```